# Angular - Menu with categories and items in category (neater and cleaner solution)

Tags: angular, menu

I have tried to implement super simple menu with categories and items inside category.
It works but probably it's more elegant and clean way to do it in Angular.

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjacek/crdnpba9/41/).

If I want to add next category or next item inside one of the category then I would have to copy all:

- template variable (like #categoryX or #itemX)
- [ngClass] directive
- (click) event declaration

It's a lot of boilerplate code.

```
@Component({selector: 'menu', template: `
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__category-list">
    <li #category1 class="menu__category" 
      [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuCategory == category1}"
      (click)="onClickMenuCategory(category1)">
      <span>Categoty-A</span>
      <div class="menu__item-list-container">
        <ul class="menu__item-list">
          <li #item1 class="menu__item" 
            [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuItem == item1}"
            (click)="onClickMenuItem(item1)">
              item1
          </li>
          <li #item2 class="menu__item" 
            [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuItem == item2}"
            (click)="onClickMenuItem(item2)">
              item2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li #category2 class="menu__category" 
      [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuCategory == category2}"
      (click)="onClickMenuCategory(category2)">
      <span>Categoty-B</span>
      <div class="menu__item-list-container">
        <ul class="menu__item-list">
          <li #item3 class="menu__item" 
            [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuItem == item3}"
            (click)="onClickMenuItem(item3)">
              item3
          </li>
          <li #item4 class="menu__item" 
            [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuItem == item4}"
            (click)="onClickMenuItem(item4)">
              item4
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>`
})
class MenuComponent {
    private selectedMenuCategory;
    private selectedMenuItem;

    onClickMenuCategory(eventArgs) {
        this.selectedMenuCategory = eventArgs;
    }

    onClickMenuItem(eventArgs) {
        this.selectedMenuItem = eventArgs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to complete by yourself?
I would recommend this [AngularMenu](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), you only need the json for the menu items (doesn't matter the levels) and it does everything for you.

Comment: It seems cool but I would like to build something simpler myself to lern more Angular.